# Using a programmatically created UITableViewCell subclass in Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I'm working on a table view with a custom cell that has been created programmatically, with no usage of IB. I've looked around on Google and asked around in NSChat, but I still can't get it to work. It just displays the default table view. Thanks in advance!

EventCell.swift

```
import UIKit

class EventCell: UITableViewCell {

    var eventName: UILabel = UILabel()
    var eventCity: UILabel = UILabel()
    var eventTime: UILabel = UILabel()

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        self.contentView.addSubview(eventName)
        self.contentView.addSubview(eventCity)
        self.contentView.addSubview(eventTime)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        eventName = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(20, 10, self.bounds.size.width - 40, 25))
        eventCity = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0))
        eventTime = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0))

    }

}
```

ViewController.swift

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

    var events: Dictionary<String, [String]> = ["0": ["Monroe Family", "La Cañada", "8:30"]]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self;
        tableView.delegate = self;

        tableView.registerClass(EventCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "EventCell")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return events.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cellIdendifier: String = "EventCell"

        var cell: EventCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdendifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as EventCell
        cell = EventCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: cellIdendifier)

        if let i = events[String(indexPath.row)] {
            cell.eventName.text = i[0]
            cell.eventCity.text = i[1]
            cell.eventTime.text = i[2]
        }

        cell.sizeToFit()

        return cell


    }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/ericcgu/TableViewCellWithAutoLayoutiOS8

Comment: let cellIdendifier: String = "EventCell" since cellIdentifier is not mutated.

Comment: let cell: EventCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdendifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! EventCell since cell is not mutated and force downcast using !

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Ok first a few important comments.

**First**, you are needlessly creating your own new cell every time the table view requests a cell instead of reusing old cells. You should remove this line:

```
cell = EventCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: cellIdendifier)
```

That is unnecessary because dequeue will automatically create new cells as needed based on the class you have registered for the given identifier.

**Second**, you should not be using the main screen bounds when laying out your code. This will break down if your table view is not the full width. Instead, you can use `self.bounds` so it is always relative to the cell itself.

**Third**, you should not be calling setNeedsLayout or layoutIfNeeded because if that method is called, it is already laying out everything again.

**Fourth**, you should register your table view cell class before setting the table view data source just in case UITableView every starts requesting things from data source when the data source is set.

**Fifth**, two of your subviews have a size of 0,0 so they are not going to show up anyway.

If this code is indeed running without crashing then you are creating EventCells because you are doing a forced casting from the result of the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath`. That means you simply have a layout / display / data issue.

Comment: Would self.bounds be the same as self.contentView.bounds in this case?

Comment: Hello! I have a question, if I have a custom init, with my own parameters, how would you approach this? is it impossible to dequeue the cells then? I would always have to create them?

Comment: @PMT Your custom init should accept a reuse identifier and then pass it along to the designated `init(style:reuseIdentifier:)`. Then you can dequeue it just like normal.

Comment: @drewag but the dequeue function won't use my custom one, and if I init it manually then the dequeue is not doing anything because I am always initializing it anyways right? Is there a way to know if the dequeue is creating a new cell (then I can use my own init) or if it is reusing one (then I let it be and I don't do the init)?. I think in the past the dequeue would return a nil when it couldn't reuse a cell, so you could do something like, if cell == nil { <my custom init>}  but now it always returns a cell so I have no idea

Comment: @PMT If you want a custom initializer, you should fall back to using `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:)` (no index path parameter). This works like you describe: returns nil if it wants a new cell initialized. And this means you no longer need to register the class with the tableview ahead of time.

Comment: Holly molly thanks a lot!! I was always using the one with indexPath parameter, I didn't even know about this one :D

Answer (score 28):

I had the same question. I applied the advice in @drewag's answer, but there were some additional issues. Below is a bare-bones, proof-of-concept example that shows how to use a programmatically created `UITableViewCell` subclass.

The image below is what it should look like. The yellow rectangles are `UILabel` subviews in the custom cells.

[image]

## Code

Here is the UITableViewCell subclass. It's job is to initialize the cell and its content, add the subviews, and layout the subviews.

```
import UIKit
class MyCustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    var myLabel = UILabel()

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        myLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
        self.contentView.addSubview(myLabel)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        myLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 0, width: 70, height: 30)
    }
}
```

Here is the view controller code.

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    let myArray = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
    let cellReuseIdendifier = "cell"


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.registerClass(MyCustomCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellReuseIdendifier)

        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myArray.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellReuseIdendifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCustomCell
        cell.myLabel.text = myArray[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
}
```

## Notes:

- I used a regular `UIViewController` rather than a `UITableViewController`. If you use a `UITableViewController` then remove the `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` protocol references since these are redundant for a `UITableViewController`. You also won't need the `@IBOutlet tableView` line.
- The main problem line I found in the original question was `eventName = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(...))`. Instead it should have been `eventName.frame = CGRect(...)`

Answer (score 3):

Your particular code does not work because it is creating new UILabels in EventCell.layoutSubviews. Only the initial UILabels are getting added to the view tree and their sizes are probably 0'd.

I'm guessing you meant to update their frames, e.g. update the EventCell class method:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    eventName.frame = CGRectMake(20, 10, self.bounds.size.width - 40, 25)
    eventCity.frame = CGRectMake(<actual size>)
    eventTime.frame = CGRectMake(<actual size>)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use lazy instantiation in swift to avoid having to drop into layoutSubviews / view life cycle dance.

```
class EventCell: UITableViewCell {
  lazy public  var lblName = {
    return UILabel (frame: CGRectMake(10, 0, self.bounds.size.width , 40))
    }()

 lazy public  var lblCity = {
    return UILabel (frame: CGRectMake(10, 40, self.bounds.size.width , 20))
    }()
 lazy public  var lblTime = {
    return UILabel (frame: CGRectMake(self.bounds.size.width - 80, 10, , 25))
    }()


  override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    self.contentView.addSubview(lblName)
    self.contentView.addSubview(lblCity)
    self.contentView.addSubview(lblTime)
  }

}
```