# cells must be retrieved by calling - dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath

Tags: uitableview, uicollectionview, swift5

Problem encountered:

> the cell returned from -collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: does not have a reuseIdentifier - cells must be retrieved by calling - dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:"

In my TableViewCell, I have a CollectionViewCell.

```
import UIKit

protocol CollectionViewTableViewCellDelegate: AnyObject {
    func collectionViewTableViewCellDidTapCell(_ cell: CollectionViewTableViewCell, viewModel: TitlePreviewViewModel)
}

class CollectionViewTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    static let identifier = "CollectionViewTableViewCellId"
    
    weak var delegate: CollectionViewTableViewCellDelegate?
    
    private var titles: [Title] = [Title]()
    
    private let collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 140, height: 200)
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.register(TitleCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: TitleCollectionViewCell.identifier)
        return collectionView
    }()
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        
        contentView.addSubview(collectionView)
        
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
    }
    
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError()
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        collectionView.frame = contentView.bounds
    }
    
    
    public func configure(with titles: [Title]) {
        self.titles = titles
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            self?.collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

I extend this class CollectionViewTableViewCell as follows:

```
extension CollectionViewTableViewCell: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: TitleCollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? TitleCollectionViewCell else {
            return UICollectionViewCell()
        }
        
       
        //-- get the specific data from the pass-in Data
        
        guard let model = titles[indexPath.row].poster_path else {
            return UICollectionViewCell()
        }
        
        //- pass data to TitleCollectionViewCell
        cell.configure(with: model)
        
        return cell
    }
```

In my Viewcontroller:

```
 I have UItableView to retrieve the cell data as follows:
```

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell    {
            
        
            guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CollectionViewTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? CollectionViewTableViewCell else {
                
                return UITableViewCell()
            }
           
            cell.delegate = self
```

Base on the Problem: for UItableView,there is no such dequeue method: dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier.

How to solve this problem?

Thanks. Please kindly help me.

Comment: The error means what it says: You have to assign the identifier to the cell in the Attributes Inspector of the storyboard. And force unwrap the cell `as! CollectionViewTableViewCell` and remove the `else` expression. If the code crashes it reveals a **design** mistake which can be fixed immediately.

Comment: in this class: CollectionViewTableViewCell, I have declared static let identifier = "CollectionViewTableViewCellId" . I am using programmatic approach. Im not familiar with storyBoard. Can advise what I need. The above is the explanation for crash. Thanks

Comment: I tried this,but same error : let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CollectionViewTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewTableViewCell    Thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with the programmatic stuff. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27585409/using-a-programmatically-created-uitableviewcell-subclass-in-swift

Comment: After taking your advise, I realized I should not use Guard let and make changes in many part using Guard Let as there may be empty string. So, you are right. I should use LET. Thanks for your advise.